# Mean/Sum over cells of array in R

Tags: r

Suppose that we have an array in R

```
A = array(1,c(4,4,200000))
```

Is there an automatic way that I can get the mean/sum over cells for the 200000 matrices?

Comment: Can you create a _minimal_ example and show expected output?

Comment: @markus Yea I can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Assuming that you are asking for one mean for each of the 20,000 matrices, i.e. a 20,000 long vector whose elements are each a mean of one of the 20,000 matrices, use `apply` as shown.  We check that against the same calculation written out.

```
A = array(1:24, c(2, 3, 4))

res1 <- apply(A, 3, mean)
res2 <- c(mean(A[,,1]), mean(A[,,2]), mean(A[,,3]), mean(A[,,4]))

identical(res1, res2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** or based on the comment below you likely want:

```
out1 <- apply(A, 1:2, mean)
out2 <- (A[,,1] + A[,,2] + A[,,3] + A[,,4])/4
identical(out1, out2)
## [1] TRUE

out1
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   10   12   14
## [2,]   11   13   15
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples! Based on what you wrote, what I'm seeking to find is, for example, the mean over the (1,1) for the 4 matrices that you displayed, i.e. (1+7+13+19)/4 or equivalently the sum.

Comment: Have added that.